# Test-path on list of computers

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to check if a folder exists on multiple computers using powershell.

I've started my script but have gotten myself muddled. How do I get the computer name from my serverlist.txt into the test path cmdlet?

```
$a = Get-Content 'c:\Users\jason\Documents\Scripts\Serverlist.txt' foreach  ($i in $a)  {Test-Path "\\$a\c$\program files\folder"}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I would do it. Pipe the file content to `Select-Object` and create two properties for each name, ComputerName and FileExist, where the later value is the result of `Test-Path`.

```
Get-Content c:\Users\jason\Documents\Scripts\Serverlist.txt | `
   Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\program files\folder"}}
```

You should expect output similar to:

```
ComputerName FolderExist
------------ -----------
Computer1    False
Computer2    True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = Get-Content 'c:\Users\jason\Documents\Scripts\Serverlist.txt' 

$b = $a | %  { $_ + " - " + @(Test-Path $_)}
```

$b now contain list of server and true or false based on test-path value

if you need all in $a variable:

```
$a = Get-Content 'c:\Users\jason\Documents\Scripts\Serverlist.txt' |  %  { $_ + " - " + @(Test-Path $_)}
```